# Creating and disposing KeyVaultClient in .NET

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, azure-keyvault

Little confused what are the best practices for creating and disposing `KeyVaultClient` objects.

I am currently instantiating `KeyVaultClient` in the following way:

```cs
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();

_keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback), httpClient);
```

I am currently creating `httpClient` using an injected `IHttpClientFactory`. What does `KeyVaultClient` actually do if I don't supply the `HttpClient`?  I assume it is creating it's own instance of `HttpClient`, but how does it manage that instance?

`KeyVaultClient` implements `IDisposable`.  Obviously under the hood `KeyVaultClient` is using a `HttpClient` instance and I have heard in many places that its not a good idea to dispose of `HttpClient` after each usage (say a single GET call). Does this mean I should be avoiding the disposing of `KeyVaultClient` as well as it will dispose my provided `httpClient` instance?

Any clarification on this would be great.

Comment: The source code is freely available, just check it out

Comment: lol you could literally say that about anything in .NET

Comment: I know right, what a time to be alive :)

Comment: It looks like you are using the previous KeyVault SDK, please have a look here for the latest version: https://aka.ms/azsdklist

The new SDKs manage the http lifecycle for you.

Comment: @JonGallant I am currently using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault 3.0.5 (latest).  I didn't realise MS has broken up Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault into different 3 packages (Secrets, Keys and Certificates) and wants people to move over!

Answer (score 2):

If the `HttpClient` is created with the default constructor it takes care of holding all resources and also disposes them on its own dispose. When using the `HttpClient` from the factory it uses a different constructor providing its own `HttpMessageHandler` (that's the one that will hold the socket). In this specific case the implementation will be taken from a pool in the factory (that still holds a reference to it) and calling dispose on the `HttpClient` will call dispose on the `HttpMessageHandler`, but that won't close the resources, but putting it back into the pool as available for the next client. Thous avoiding an overflow of open sockets.

So by providing an client from the factory and injecting this into the `KeyVaultClient` that only has a scoped lifetime will taking care of managing the sockets and is IMHO the best way of usage. Instead, registering the `KeyVaultClient` as singleton will lead to problems that the `HttpClientFactory` helps to avoid.

Comment: So in your opinion if I'm providing the HttpClient via the factory to KeyVaultClient then its still best to call KeyVaultClient.Dispose() because it in turn will call HttpClient.Dispose() which will (because I used the factory) not close resources but put them back in the pool?